# React native mqtt - publish when button is pressed

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mqtt

I use [sp-react-native-mqtt](https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-mqtt) for my project, and I would want to publish a message to a mqtt topic when a button is pressed.

Mqtt connect code, which returns a promise:

```
    MQTT.createClient({
  uri: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
  clientId: 'your_client_id'
}).then(function(client) {

  client.on('closed', function() {
    console.log('mqtt.event.closed');
  });

  client.on('error', function(msg) {
    console.log('mqtt.event.error', msg);
  });

  client.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log('mqtt.event.message', msg);
  });

  client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    client.subscribe('/data', 0);
    client.publish('/data', "test", 0, false);
  });

  client.connect();
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Edit:

If I am saving the client in a variable, and i use the variable to publish I am getting this error:

[image: react native mqtt publish error]

```
  let mqttClient = null;

MQTT.createClient({
        uri: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
        clientId: 'your_client_id',
      })
        .then(function (client) {
          mqttClient = client;
    .... }

       <Button
              title="test"
              onPress={() => {
                mqttClient.publish('/data', 'message');
              }}
            />
```

How should I handle this?
Or if you have any other sugestions on how to use mqtt in react native, or another package for mqtt.

Thank you!

Comment: As a rule topics really shouldn't start with a leading `/` (while allowed in the spec, it will break things like shared subscriptions, and it adds an extra null to the start of all topic trees).  As for the question what have you tried (e.g. save `client` to a variable you can access from the button handler)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I tried, but i am getting an error. I edited my question to place there image with the error.

Comment: It's **very** unlikely that error has anything to do with publishing an MQTT message. It's trying to convert a Double object to a native double, not something the publish would normally need.

Comment: It's interesting, if I add QoS and retain parameter, i don-t get that error, but it doesn-t send the message either.

  mqttClient.publish('/data', 'dsdsadasdsadas', 0, true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after all, @hardillb answer helped me.

At first it didnt send the message even if I saved the **client** in a variable because I saved it before the client was connected.

Working code:

```
  let mqttClient = null;

  MQTT.createClient({
    uri: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
    clientId: 'your_client_id',
  })
    .then(function (client) {
      client.on('closed', function () {
        console.log('mqtt.event.closed');
      });

      client.on('error', function (msg) {
        console.log('mqtt.event.error', msg);
      });

      client.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('mqtt.event.message', msg);
      });

      client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connected');
        client.subscribe('data', 0);
        mqttClient = client;
      });

      client.connect();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

       <Button
          title="test"
          onPress={() => {
            //   console.log(mqttClient);
            mqttClient.publish('data', 'This is the answer', 0, true);
          }}
        />
```

Thank you @hardillb!